# Can any one help me how to prove this therom in coq

Tags: coq

```
~ (exists x:D, ~ R x)->(forall y:D, R y)
```

I have worked on it for quite a long time, but it seems that I cannot use the left part of the implication well.

This is the first part of my code:

```
Parameter D: Set.
Parameter x: D.
Parameter y: D.
Parameter R: D->Prop.
Lemma b:  ~(exists x:D, ~ (R x))->(forall y:D, (R y)).
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to write the rest of of the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague, as you don't specify what `D` and `R` are, and where you are stuck in your proof. Try providing a minimal working example, with an explicit `fail` tactic for where you're stuck in the proof.

In *classical logic* (the one you're use to in maths), as you have the *excluded middle* rule, you can always do a case analysis on whether something is true or false. In vanilla Coq, built for *intuitionistic logic*, it's not the case. Your result is actually *not provable* if the predicate `R` is not decidable (if it's not either true or false on every input : `forall (x:D), R x \/ ~R x`), if the type D is not empty.

Try adding the decidability of R as an hypothesis and reprove it. It should follow more or less this structure (the key being the case analysis on whether `(R y)` is true or false) :

```
Parameter D: Set.
Parameter R: D -> Prop.

Lemma yourGoal :
    (forall x, R x \/ ~ R x) -> (* Decidability of R *)
    ~ ( exists x, ~ (R x) )->
    forall y, (R y).
Proof.
    intros Hdec Hex y. (* naming the hypothesis for convenience *)
    specialize (Hdec y).
    destruct Hdec as [H_Ry_is_true | H_Ry_is_false]. (* case analysis, creates two goals *)
    + (* (R y) is true, which is our goal. *)
        assumption.
    + (* (R y) is false, which contradicts Hex *)
        exfalso. (* transform your goal into False *)
        apply Hex.
        (* should be easy from here, using the [exists] tactic *)
Qed.
```

Ps: this exact result (and its link with excluded middle) is mentioned in Software foundations, which is a great resource to learn Coq and logic : https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/Logic.html#not_exists_dist

Comment: Thanks. I forget to claim that R is decidable. But even though it is decidable, I just can not work out the rest of the code to prove the lemma. Can you help me with that?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the structure of the proof. You can finish the proof with only two tactics, namely `exists` and `apply`. Good luck !